# Reg_exp Not like - Oracle 11g

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g

I'm running Oracle 11g trying to find all entries where record in NOT containing characters listed below.

List of Valid Characters: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå0123456789èüeäö.,’&-/`

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE NOT
REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(UPPER(name1)),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå0123456789èüeäö.,’&-/')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Values that do not contain any of those characters; or values that contain any characters not in that list? Which isn't quite the same thing. Why `upper()` when you're comparing lower-case characters?

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. "values that contain any characters not in that list"
There is no reason to use upper, I previously only had upper-case characters in list, I have simply forgot to remove the function

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: Reg_exp operator returns valid names

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE NOT
REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(name1),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå0123456789èüeäö.,’&-/')


NAME
-------------------------
De Haan
Greenberg J.
Khoo Lee
Gee A.
Greene E.
Lee A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in your REGEXP_LIKE is a lengthy pattern, starting with `abc....` upto  `-/`. Since your table is unlikely to contain a name with this pattern, it will not match any of the rows. The presence of NOT will invert this and you will get all the rows present in the table.

What you should be doing here is match any of the characters and not pattern as a whole. So you should enclose it in [square brackets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS232).

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(UPPER(name1)),'[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå0123456789èüeäö.,’&-/]');
```

But this will work only for names containing only the invalid characters. If a name contains both valid and invalid characters, regex will match and NOT will cause the row to be not displayed.

So, you should use ^ inside the square brackets to exclude the valid characters and remove NOT from the condition.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(UPPER(name1)),'[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå0123456789èüeäö.,’&-/]');
```

This will match only those names that contain characters not present in the regex.

You can simplify this further by using [:alnum:] or \w character class. This will match all alphabets and numbers. You can also get rid of upper function.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(name1),'[^[:alnum:].,’&-/]');
```

Example:

```
SQL> with x(y) as (
        select 'y.s&'||'d' from dual union all
        select '4rc y'     from dual union all
        select 'üe'        from dual union all
        select 'æøå'       from dual union all
        select 'Z%'        from dual union all
        select '!'         from dual
        )
SELECT * FROM x
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( TRIM(y),'[^[:alnum:].,’&-/]'); 

Y
------
4rc y
Z%
!
```

---

***UPDATE:***

- \w matches underscore also. It is equivalent to [[:alnum:]_].
- You can get rid of TRIM function, if you add space character to list of valid characters.

Comment: Adding ^ into the brackets seems to have solved the problem! Thanks alot for clarifying. Note: People with two names I.e
Don Joe are still returned. I assume I need to account for the extra space between names. May I kindy ask that you please elaborate on this as well. Many thanks

Comment: There is no space in list of valid characters. So no wonder it is treating a space as invalid character. You can account for that by adding it in regex. `'[^[:alnum:].,’&-/ ]'`